# Best way to handle nested exceptions through layer in Java

Tags: java, exception

I have the scenario:

```
//package
org.system.business
    |
    +-- catalog
    |
    +-- validators
```

Inside catalog package I have **catalog** classes that represent some **CRUDs** and a **CatalogException** exception.

Inside validators package I have **validation** classes and a **ValidationException** exception.

For the entire system I have generic exceptions like **MissingException**, etc...

Well.... in code above...:

```
//web service layer calling the catalogservice
public MyObject insertSomething(MyObject something){
    insert(something);
}

//catalogservice calling validation
public MyObject insert(MyObject something){
    MyValidator.validate(something);
}

//myvalidator throwing exception
public static validate(MyObject something){
    //some validation
    throw new ValidationException(new MissingException("Some message"));
}
```

...which is the better way for handle the exceptions:

1. Catch **ValidationException** in catalog call and wrap with **CatalogException** and maybe throw a **BusinessException**?
2. Just propagate ValidationException?
3. Some other scheme?

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what the caller would logically expect. Option 1. seems best. Do try and use checked exceptions for high level (business logic) exceptions.

A validator usually doesn't throw exceptions. It's job is to validate things, so it should expect wrong values. If validation fails it should return `false` or a `Result` but not an exception.

Comment: Ok, but... how can I show an error for User if I don't threw an exception and my return type is MyObject?

Comment: By validating user input *before* calling the catalog service. In general you should save exceptions for exceptional circumstances. What if you want to guide or give hints to the user? If your architecture only allows this to be handled by exceptions your validator will be hidden from view to perform the necessary checks. Of course, within the catalog service you can still call the validator and wrap the result in a ValidatorException if you must.

Answer (score 0):

If its a user facing application, then you should never propagate any "technical exception" to the UI. At times, if unavoidable, they should see the "business exception".